# How to increase the size of request in ab benchmarking tool?

Tags: performance, performance-testing, apachebench

I am testing with *ab* - Apache HTTP server benchmarking tool.

Can I increase the size of the request in Apache (now I see 1 request has the size of 146 bytes).

I tried to increase the size of TCP send/receive buffer (-b option), but It seems does not work. Because I still see the "Total transferred" is 146 bytes.

Do you know any way to increase the size of the request? (change the source code or something).

Or if it is impossible, can you give me a suggestion about some tools which are similar to *ab* but it can increase the size of the request.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Although `-b` option does seem like it should've worked, I can't say for sure as I haven't used.

Alternatively, have you tried sending a dummy large file in your POST request? that can be accomplished with the `-p` option followed by a plain text file for instance, that you can either create yourself or Google for something like "generate large file in bytes online" that you can download and pass into the command.

As far as alternatives go, I've heard another open source project called [httpperf](https://github.com/httperf/httperf) from HP to be a great option as well, though I doubt we're unable to figure it out how to do it with Apache Benchmark.